# CSS layout: text overwriting footer, text hidden behind image, etc

Tags: css, layout

Who can help me to optimize this CSS layout?
The problems are:
-The footer on the left size is overwritten by the text above
-Why can't I see a vertical scrollbar?
-The text on lower right disappers behind the picture
-The text on lower right does not reach to the bottom
-How can I make the font size in the lower right box proportional to the window?

Please help!

The image p1.jpg used in this script can be found in
 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/u9hzlj2vz6hk229/p1.jpg?dl=0

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<style type="text/css">

.fixed_hdr_left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25 px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.fixed_hdr_right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25 px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.fixed_main_left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid magenta;
}
.fixed_main_right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.fixed_main_low {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 14;
  font-family: Arial;
  top: 60%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.fixed_footer_left {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.fixed_footer_right {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
</style>

<head>
<title>css layout test</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fixed_hdr_left"> CSS layout</div>
<div class="fixed_hdr_right"> using position; fixed;</div>
<div class="fixed_footer_left"> Copyright (c) 2015 by me and others</div>
<div class="fixed_footer_right"> Happy New Year!</div>
<div class="fixed_main_low"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. </div>
<div class="fixed_main_right"> <img src="images\p1.jpg" /> </div>
<div class="fixed_main_left">
<ul>
D E S I D E R A T A
<li>Go placidly amid the noise and haste, And remember what peace there may be in silence. As far as possible without surrender be on good terms with all persons.
<li>Speak your truth quietly & clearly; and listen to others, even the dull & ignorant; they too have their story.
<li>Avoid loud & aggressive persons, they are vexations to the spirit. If you compare yourself with others, you may become vain & bitter; for always there will be greater and lesser persons than yourself. Enjoy your achievements as well as your plans.
<li>Keep interested in your own career, however humble; it is a real possession in the changing future of time. Exercise caution in your business affairs; for the world is full of trickery. But let this not blind you to what virtue there is; many persons strive for high ideals; and everywhere life is full of heroism.
<li>Be yourself. Especially, do not feign affection. Neither be cynical about love; for in the face of all aridity & disenchantment it is perenniall as the grass.
<li>Take kindly the counsel of the years, gracefully surrendering the things of youth. Nurture strength of spirit to shield you in sudden misfortune. But do not distress yourself with imaginings. Many fears are born of fatigue & loneliness. Beyond wholesome discipline, be gentle with yourself.
<li>You are a child of the universe, no less than the trees & the stars; you have a right to be here. And whether or not it is clear to you, no doubt the universe is unfolding as it should.
<li>Therefore be at peace with God, whatever you conceive Him to be, and whatever your labours & aspirations, in the noisy confusion of life keep peace with your soul. With all its sham, drudgery & broken dreams, it is still a beautiful world.
<li>Be cheerful. Strive to be happy.
written in 1927 by Max Ehrmann (1872-1945)
</ul>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you tell us wich browser you are using to reproduce this behaviour ? Edit : put this in jsfiddle for convenience http://jsfiddle.net/kykndnbm/

Comment: I am using Firefox 34.0

Comment: The behaviour in IE 11 is the same

Comment: Why is all your elements position fixed?

Comment: You should use position:fixed for precise use only, you can do your template with things like float. Do you absolutely need to work with fixed properties?

Comment: I found it completely impossible to do a layout similar to this using postion:relative; there are lots of more problems than I am having here. Also using float:right or float:left does not solve the problems I have described,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there any spacial reason for "fixed" positioning being used for all divisions in the layout?
the layout required can be easily created with "relative" positioning (which will make the layout responsive as well). other options include using a css library like pure.css.

here i have created the layout you required.

edit height properties of divisions.(heights and colors are just to display layout)

```
            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <title></title>
               <style>
                  body{
                  text-align: center;
                  }

                  #topleft{
                    width: 69%;
                    height: 100px;
                    background-color: black; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #topright{
                    width: 30%;
                    height: 100px;
                    background-color: red; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #leftMiddle{
                    width: 30%;
                    height: 300px;
                    background-color: green; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #rightMiddle{
                    width: 69%;
                    height: 300px;
                    background-color: white; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #rm1{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 150px;
                    background-color: yellow; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #rm2{
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 150px;
                    background-color: orange; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #footerLeft{
                    width: 80%;
                    height: 50px;
                    background-color: green; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #footerRight{
                    width: 19%;
                    height: 50px;
                    background-color: gray; 
                    display: inline-block;
                  }

                  #footer{
                    position: fixed;
                    bottom: 0px;
                    left: 0px;
                    width: 100%;
                  }


               </style>
            </head>
            <body>

               <div id="topleft">
               </div>

               <div id="topright">
               </div>

               <div id="leftMiddle">
               </div>

               <div id="rightMiddle">
                 <div id="rm1">
                 </div>

                 <div id="rm2">
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div id="footer">
                   <div id="footerLeft">
                   </div>

                   <div id="footerRight">
                   </div>
               </div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Comment: I must confess I am an absolute beginner with CSS, but what I have tried until now with position:relative resulted only in a mess.

Comment: Sorry, but it didn't help. If you fill out the empty <div> blocks with the text and img you see no problem was solved.

Comment: adding "overflow" property of divisions would do it. try adding div{ overflow: hidden } into css.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do should be something like that [link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kykndnbm/3/), I've modified your code, since you are a beginner I can give you some advices from my own experiences

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.fixed_hdr_left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 25 px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.fixed_hdr_right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25 px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}


.fixed_main_left {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 90%;
  border: 2px solid magenta;
}
.fixed_main_right {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  max-height: 80%;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
}
.fixed_main_low {
  position: fixed;
  font-size: 14;
  font-family: Arial;
  top: 60%;
  left: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4em;
  border: 2px solid green;
}

.fixed_footer_left {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.fixed_footer_right {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  border: 2px solid green;
}
body {
  margin-bottom: 120px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<div class="fixed_hdr_left"> CSS layout</div>
<div class="fixed_hdr_right"> using position; fixed;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="right">
            <div class="fixed_main_right"> <img src="images\p1.jpg" /> </div>
<div class="fixed_main_low"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus imperdiet, nulla et dictum interdum, nisi lorem egestas odio, vitae scelerisque enim ligula venenatis dolor. Maecenas nisl est, ultrices nec congue eget, auctor vitae massa. Fusce luctus vestibulum augue ut aliquet. Mauris ante ligula, facilisis sed ornare eu, lobortis in odio. Praesent convallis urna a lacus interdum ut hendrerit risus congue. Nunc sagittis dictum nisi, sed ullamcorper ipsum dignissim ac. In at libero sed nunc venenatis imperdiet sed ornare turpis. Donec vitae dui eget tellus gravida venenatis. Integer fringilla congue eros non fermentum. Sed dapibus pulvinar nibh tempor porta. Cras ac leo purus. Mauris quis diam velit. </div>
        </div>
<div class="fixed_main_left">
<ul>
D E S I D E R A T A
<li>Go placidly amid the noise and haste, And remember what peace there may be in silence. As far as possible without surrender be on good terms with all persons.
    </li>
<li>Speak your truth quietly & clearly; and listen to others, even the dull & ignorant; they too have their story.
    </li>
<li>Avoid loud & aggressive persons, they are vexations to the spirit. If you compare yourself with others, you may become vain & bitter; for always there will be greater and lesser persons than yourself. Enjoy your achievements as well as your plans.
    </li>
<li>Keep interested in your own career, however humble; it is a real possession in the changing future of time. Exercise caution in your business affairs; for the world is full of trickery. But let this not blind you to what virtue there is; many persons strive for high ideals; and everywhere life is full of heroism.
    </li>
<li>Be yourself. Especially, do not feign affection. Neither be cynical about love; for in the face of all aridity & disenchantment it is perenniall as the grass.
    </li>
<li>Take kindly the counsel of the years, gracefully surrendering the things of youth. Nurture strength of spirit to shield you in sudden misfortune. But do not distress yourself with imaginings. Many fears are born of fatigue & loneliness. Beyond wholesome discipline, be gentle with yourself.
    </li>
<li>You are a child of the universe, no less than the trees & the stars; you have a right to be here. And whether or not it is clear to you, no doubt the universe is unfolding as it should.
    </li>
<li>Therefore be at peace with God, whatever you conceive Him to be, and whatever your labours & aspirations, in the noisy confusion of life keep peace with your soul. With all its sham, drudgery & broken dreams, it is still a beautiful world.
    </li>
<li>Be cheerful. Strive to be happy.
written in 1927 by Max Ehrmann (1872-1945)
    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
<div class="fixed_footer_left"> Copyright (c) 2015 by me and others</div>
<div class="fixed_footer_right"> Happy New Year!</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

- I know fixed properties look familiar but prefer using float or fancier CSS
- Try to organize your element as naturally as possible, as example your footer was the first thing declared in your page as it should have been the last thing
- Don't forget to close your tags (many

  without

  to close it), many of HTML tag must be close to wrap the information you are providing, except some self closing tag like

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see any difference with the changed code, except that now the text on le right is _above_ the image instead of _below_.

Comment: The  link to JSFiddle looks nice, but it doesn't use the image p1.jpg, and that makes a big difference!

Comment: Yes because the image is on your computer, it can't be seen on jsfiddle wich is on a distant server